# Creating free website with accounts without personal data administrator

Tags: authentication

I would like to create free web page. The application should have to possibility to authentice user.
Unfortunatelly in Poland there is RODO and when I store email addresses ind databse I need to inform user who is personal database administrator, so I need to publish my Family name and private address (I'm don't have company).
Do you have an idea, how to make web page with authentication without storing personal data like email or bypas RODO regulation?